# Display column names that are only factors

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract only column names that are factor. For example, in iris dataset, last column is a factor, so only Species (column name and not entire column) should be extracted

```
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
> str(head(iris))
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use :

```
names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.factor)]
#[1] "Species"
```

Or using `Filter` :

```
names(Filter(is.factor, iris))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which involves the `dplyr` package (if by chance you are already using it in your own project) is

```
names(iris %>% select_if(is.factor))
```

or equivalently (choose the one you like more)

```
iris %>% select_if(is.factor) %>% names()
```

---

Output

```
# [1] "Species"
```